# Общая функция для объектов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть несколько созданных объектов на сцене, на них висят одинаковые скрипты. В этом скрипте имеется функция func(). Мне нужно, чтобы эта функция у каждого объекта была разная. Можно ли это реализовать, не привязывая новые скрипты?

Comment: Что значит эта функция у каждого объекта разная? Можно как-то поподробнее? Что-то не очень понятно.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать MoonSharp, прекрасное дополнение к Unity. http://moonsharp.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться паттерном проектирования под названиием [Стратегия](http://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.1.php).

Абстрактный пример:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    void Algorithm();
}

public class ConcreteStrategy1 : IStrategy
{
    public void Algorithm()
    {}
}

public class ConcreteStrategy2 : IStrategy
{
    public void Algorithm()
    {}
}

public class Context
{
    public IStrategy ContextStrategy { get; set; }

    public Context(IStrategy _strategy)
    {
        ContextStrategy = _strategy;
    }

    public void ExecuteAlgorithm()
    {
        ContextStrategy.Algorithm();
    }
}
```

Принципы работы с C# в Unity3d отличаются, по этому вам придется несколько по другому воспользоваться данным шаблоном, а именно унаследовать Context от `MonoBehaviour` и присваивать стратегии через инспектор объекта.